# Java Reading Text Inside File

Tags: java, file

![enter image description here][1]I have a file called notes.txt containing several lines of text that I want show to my JPanel.

Here is my code:

```
private void loadNotes() {
    File file = new File("notes.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fs));

            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
                if (br.readLine() != null) {
                    String note = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(note);
                    notes[i] = new JCheckBox(note, false);
                    panel.add(notes[i]);
                    panel.revalidate();
                    panel.repaint();
                }
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
}
            br.close();
```

This method grabs the lines from the file and prints out the check boxes.  So if I have 4  notes then it prints out 4 checkboxes.  However, it doesn't print out the text?  Why not?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDtMm.png

Comment: Would like to see more of your code.

Comment: Does the `syso` print the value of note?

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `br.readLine()` twice in the `for` loop so every second line of the file will be skipped. Assign the `note` variable at the start of the loop

```
String note;
for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if ((note = br.readLine()) != null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVX8Y.png My result.  I removed the if (bt.readLine() != null) correct? I just want each line to print out.... -.-

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: No spaces, no extra boxes.  So aggravating  Input file: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SDtMm.png

Comment: Couldnt have known that, kinda important to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to help us diagnose such issues :)